# install googlemaps package python

Tags: python, google-maps, pip

I am trying to install GoogleMaps Package

```
pip install GoogleMaps
```

I am getting this error:

```
C:\Users\NA401134>pip install GoogleMaps
Collecting GoogleMaps
  Using cached googlemaps-2.5.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    warning: no files found matching 'NOTICE'

Installed c:\users\na401134\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-y5t07ucg\googlemaps\.eggs\requests-2.18.4-py3.5.egg
Searching for certifi>=2017.4.17
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/certifi/
Best match: certifi 2017.7.27.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/20/d0/3f7a84b0c5b89e94abbd073a5f00c7176089f526edb056686751d5064cbd/certifi-2017.7.27.1.tar.gz#md5=48e8370da8b370a16e223ee9c7b6b063
Processing certifi-2017.7.27.1.tar.gz
Writing C:\Users\NA401134\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-ttda9z_e\certifi-2017.7.27.1\setup.cfg
Running certifi-2017.7.27.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\NA401134\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-ttda9z_e\certifi-2017.7.27.1\egg-dist-tmp-k3p_29q4
creating c:\users\na401134\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-y5t07ucg\googlemaps\.eggs\certifi-2017.7.27.1-py3.5.egg
Extracting certifi-2017.7.27.1-py3.5.egg to c:\users\na401134\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-y5t07ucg\googlemaps\.eggs

Installed c:\users\na401134\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-y5t07ucg\googlemaps\.eggs\certifi-2017.7.27.1-py3.5.egg
Searching for urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/urllib3/
Best match: urllib3 1.22
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/ee/11/7c59620aceedcc1ef65e156cc5ce5a24ef87be4107c2b74458464e437a5d/urllib3-1.22.tar.gz#md5=0da7bed3fe94bf7dc59ae37885cc72f7
Processing urllib3-1.22.tar.gz
Writing C:\Users\NA401134\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-n_pau25n\urllib3-1.22\setup.cfg
Running urllib3-1.22\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\NA401134\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-n_pau25n\urllib3-1.22\egg-dist-tmp-on1foee6
c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\setuptools\dist.py:285: UserWarning: Normalizing '2017.07.27.1' to '2017.7.27.1'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs\_build'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
urllib3.packages.__pycache__.six.cpython-35: module references __path__
creating c:\users\na401134\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-y5t07ucg\googlemaps\.eggs\urllib3-1.22-py3.5.egg
Extracting urllib3-1.22-py3.5.egg to c:\users\na401134\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-y5t07ucg\googlemaps\.eggs

Installed c:\users\na401134\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-y5t07ucg\googlemaps\.eggs\urllib3-1.22-py3.5.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\NA401134\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-y5t07ucg\GoogleMaps\setup.py", line 39, in <module>
    'Topic :: Internet',
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 269, in __init__
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 826, in resolve
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1085, in best_match
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 695, in find
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (idna 2.1 (c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('idna<2.7,>=2.5'))

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\NA401134\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-y5t07ucg\GoogleMaps\
```

If I run pip freeze I get:

```
C:\Users\NA401134>pip freeze
alabaster==0.7.8
anaconda-client==1.4.0
anaconda-navigator==1.2.1
argcomplete==1.0.0
astropy==1.2.1
Babel==2.3.3
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
bitarray==0.8.1
blaze==0.10.1
bokeh==0.12.0
boto==2.40.0
Bottleneck==1.1.0
cffi==1.6.0
chest==0.2.3
click==6.6
cloudpickle==0.2.1
clyent==1.2.2
colorama==0.3.7
comtypes==1.1.2
conda==4.1.6
conda-build==1.21.3
conda-env==2.5.0a0
configobj==5.0.6
contextlib2==0.5.3
cryptography==1.4
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.24
cytoolz==0.8.0
dask==0.10.0
datashape==0.5.2
decorator==4.0.10
dill==0.2.5
docutils==0.12
dynd===c328ab7
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
fastcache==1.0.2
Flask==0.11.1
Flask-Cors==2.1.2
gevent==1.1.1
greenlet==0.4.10
h5py==2.6.0
HeapDict==1.0.0
idna==2.1
imagesize==0.7.1
ipykernel==4.3.1
ipython==4.2.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
ipywidgets==4.1.1
itsdangerous==0.24
jdcal==1.2
jedi==0.9.0
Jinja2==2.8
jsonschema==2.5.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==4.3.0
jupyter-console==4.1.1
jupyter-core==4.1.0
llvmlite==0.11.0
locket==0.2.0
lxml==3.6.0
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==1.5.1
menuinst==1.4.1
mistune==0.7.2
mpmath==0.19
multipledispatch==0.4.8
nb-anacondacloud==1.1.0
nb-conda==1.1.0
nb-conda-kernels==1.0.3
nbconvert==4.2.0
nbformat==4.0.1
nbpresent==3.0.2
networkx==1.11
nltk==3.2.1
nose==1.3.7
notebook==4.2.1
numba==0.26.0
numexpr==2.6.0
numpy==1.11.1
odo==0.5.0
openpyxl==2.3.2
pandas==0.18.1
partd==0.3.4
path.py==0.0.0
pathlib2==2.1.0
patsy==0.4.1
pep8==1.7.0
pickleshare==0.7.2
Pillow==3.2.0
ply==3.8
psutil==4.3.0
py==1.4.31
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycosat==0.6.1
pycparser==2.14
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0
pyflakes==1.2.3
Pygments==2.1.3
pyOpenSSL==16.0.0
pyparsing==2.1.4
pyreadline==2.1
pytest==2.9.2
python-dateutil==2.5.3
pytz==2016.4
pywin32==220
PyYAML==3.11
pyzmq==15.2.0
qtconsole==4.2.1
QtPy==1.0.2
requests==2.10.0
rope-py3k==0.9.4.post1
ruamel-yaml===-VERSION
scikit-image==0.12.3
scikit-learn==0.17.1
scipy==0.17.1
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
sockjs-tornado==1.0.3
Sphinx==1.3.1
sphinx-rtd-theme==0.1.9
spyder==2.3.9
SQLAlchemy==1.0.13
statsmodels==0.6.1
sympy==1.0
tables==3.2.2
toolz==0.8.0
tornado==4.3
traitlets==4.2.1
unicodecsv==0.14.1
Werkzeug==0.11.10
xlrd==1.0.0
XlsxWriter==0.9.2
xlwings==0.7.2
xlwt==1.1.2
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `pip freeze` please?

Comment: I edited and added that part. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a version conflict, which can happen when you install a lot of packages in the same python environment.

To get a full list of outdated packages, use this command:

```
pip list --outdated --format=columns
```

You can try to upgrade some of your old installed packages in order for this to work.

```
pip install --upgrade requests idna GoogleMaps
```

Alternatively you can try to install an older version of GoogleMaps

```
pip install GoogleMaps==2.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `python -m pip install GoogleMaps`